# Error when importing images in SSR React App: "SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token �PNG"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parcel, server-side-rendering, parceljs

I'm trying to run SSR React (16.3.0) App using simple express server. After building and running `babel-node server.js` got error regarding imported PNG file:

/home/dev/test/src/assets/bg.png:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { �PNG
                                                              ^

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/home/dev/test/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:88:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

This is my server.js:

```
import express from 'express'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import path from 'path'

import App from './src/components/App'

const app = express()
const port = 4000

const HTMLShell = (html) => `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <title>SSR React App</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <div id="app">${html}</div>
          <script src="./app.min.js"></script>
      </body>
  </html>`

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  let html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <App />
  )

  res.send(HTMLShell(html))
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

For bundling i'm using Parcel. How to import images without having this error ?

EDIT:
Images are imported this way:

`import bgHeader from '../assets/bg.png'`

Comment: i would need to see the app code, how you use or import images

Comment: If you have something like `import myImage from '/folder/myimage.png'` you would need to run your js through a transpiler(or plugin) that understands how to handle image imports. It looks like you do not do that or you set it up wrong.

Comment: Yes, I import it like `import bgHeader from '../assets/bg.png'`

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: @Nestor I gave up and switched to next.js

Comment: any solutions ???